# How to get lamp object?

Tags: python, light

How to get lamp object?

```
def test():
    Lights = bpy.data.lamps
    for light in Lights:
        light.use_nodes = True;
        light.type="POINT";
        AdddLightIes(light)
```

#how to get light.object? and set position?

Answer (score 3):

**Blender object basics.**

The lamp objects in `bpy.data.lamps` is the data part of a lamp object `o`. A lamp object has `o.type == "LAMP"` and `o.data` is a lamp object from `bpy.data.lamps`.

To get all lamp objects in file

```
lamp_objects = [o for o in bpy.data.objects
                if o.type == 'LAMP']
```

all in file that use a lamp named "Lamp"

```
lamp = bpy.data.lamps.get("Lamp")
lamp_objects = [o for o in bpy.data.objects
                if o.type == 'LAMP' # need this since
                and o.data is lamp] # o.data is None for empties
```

for all in context scene

```
scene = bpy.context.scene
lamp_objects = [o for o in scene.objects
                if o.type == 'LAMP']
```

for all in context selected objects

```
lamp_objects = [o for o in bpy.context.selected_objects
                if o.type == 'LAMP']
```

To move all lamps to local position (0, 0, 0)

```
for o in lamp_objects:
    o.location = (0, 0, 0)
```

To move all lamps to global origin

```
for o in lamp_objects:
    o.matrix_world.translation = (0, 0, 0)
```